# Rest Assured - JsonPath extract value

Tags: rest, rest-assured

I'm trying to use Rest assured and JsonPath to extract a value from the pzSetRuleSetFilter field where the pyRuleSetName equals a certain value (TradeMarks in this case). I keep getting the error below. Any ideas on how I can fix this and extract the value would be great

invalid JSON expression:Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found '[' @ line 1, column 39.

**My Query**
System.out.println(response.jsonPath().getString("$..pxResults[?(@.pyRuleSetName == 'TradeMarks')].pzSetRuleSetFilter"));

**Sample JSON**
    pxResults
      0
        pxClass              Blah
        pyRuleSetName        AValue
        pzSetRuleSetFilter   01-01-2000
      1
        pxClass              Blah
        pyRuleSetName        TradeMarks
        pzSetRuleSetFilter   01-02-2018
    2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use JsonPath provided by rest-assured and can use the following expression to get your desired output:

```
pxResults.find { it.pyRuleSetName == 'TradeMarks' }.pzSetRuleSetFilter
```

You can know more about Rest-Assured Json Path from [here](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted#jsonpath)

Comment: What does 'psResults' represents? I am trying to convert this method to my code for the same purpose but i couldn't do.

Comment: Corrected the typo. `pxResults` is the parent node under which I'm trying to find some data as per given criteria.